# Localizing iOS app with an in-house framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, localization

We've got a project in iOS to which we've added NSLocalizedString() in order to localize it.
We also have an an in-house framework that we use which is linked in to the project. We've compiled a Localizable.strings file for both the project and the framework (in a single file) and we've created a localized Spanish version in a folder called es.lproj... However the localized strings are only appearing in the project - code which is running from within our framework are not showing the localized strings - is there something we've missed here?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using NSLocalizedStringFromTable().

See the following question:

[Split localization in many files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094377/iphone-is-it-possible-to-split-localizable-strings-in-many-files)

**Note:** that the Localized.strings files are not compiled but added as resources in the application.
The correct string is fetched during runtime.

Comment: Okay, so am I right in saying I'd create a .strings file for the library, and then a separate one for the project, and then that should work out okay?